# How to reuse/recycle GoogleMaps in Fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

A long time i used this code, to 'reuse' a GoogleMap in Fragment - when switching to another Fragment and opening the MapFragment again, the Map and all its content was as before (no zooming-in again, no need to re-set Markers, it was 'just in background' and brought to front again):

```
public class MapFragmentGoogle extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener, OnMapLoadedCallback  {
private static View rootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_google, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        //
    }
return rootView;
```

So now i switched from eclipse to AndroidStudio (i kow i'm late), which is implementing the latest PlayServices and i cannot use

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.gmap)).getMap();
```

anymore and the 'Reuse-Code" does not work anymore. I'am getting tiered about those things.

How can i have a GoogleMap, which stays exactly as it is, no new init, no zomming from space to place, not redrawing Polylines and Markersetc etc when switching to another fragment and then back to the mapfragment?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use supportmapfragment, please find the code below:

XML:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    android:id="@+id/search1"

    >
```

code:

```
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
  mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        ldb = new LocationDatabase(this);
        intentlat = null;
        intentlng = null;
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        m_map = googleMap;
        map_false = true;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        m_map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        m_map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        m_map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        m_map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        m_map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        addresses = null;

        if (intentlat == null && intentlng == null) {
            LatLng target3 = new LatLng(<latitude>, <81.488100>);
            CameraPosition nnn = CameraPosition.builder().target(target3).zoom(14).build();
            m_map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(nnn), 2000, null);
CameraPosition nnn = CameraPosition.builder().target(target3).zoom(14.0f).build();
            m_map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(nnn), 2000, null);

}
```

Comment: It is not about using supportmapfragment, it's about 'keep fragment as it is' - to not reload map on reopen fragment.

Comment: I think map loads once and stay in memory for long, as per my understanding you want to see the location on map fragment  where you left when u got inactive to that screen. If that is the case do not animate camera  and directly goto your saved instance state for latlong